# Were there pictographic glyph variants of letters, like multiocular O (ꙮ) for the word 'many-eyed' etc. in Cyrillic, in any other alphabets?

Tags: alphabets

Were there pictographic glyphs of letters that were used in some special words in any other alphabets and languages?
Like multiocular O (ꙮ) in word 'many-eyed', double monocular O (Ꙭ) for the plural or dual forms of the word 'eye', Crossed O (Ꚛ) for the word 'around' that has whose component that means 'cross' etc. in Cyrillic.

Comment: Note that the ꙮ is an alternative for the letter O. It was just used for the letter O inside for the word multi-eyed, but not for the whole word, but for one of the Os in this  word. And I think it was used just once by some scribe, it is just an oddity inspired by Ꙩ, Ꙫ and Ꙭ. Also note that it is probably better to call the language where they were used  just Church Slavonic or Old East Slavic, it was used after the classical age of Old CS.

Comment: Interesting, even the Unicode proposal https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2010/10394r-cyrillic.pdf calls it "Early" Cyrillic characters. Some 600 years after St. Cyril (though the script was invented several decades later).